# How to fix Expected Identifier/Use of undeclared identifier?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I want my sprite to move to previously desired coordinates after the screen is tapped, here is my code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [SKAction *moveNodeRight = [SKAction moveByX:100.0 y:0.0 duration:1.0];
    [_squirrelSprite runAction: moveNodeRight withKey:@"changeside"];
}
```

On the second line I get the error:

> "Expected identifier"

And it has an orange arrow under `moveNodeRight`.

On the third line I get the error:

> "Use of undeclared identifier `moveNodeRight`"

How and where would I declare these?

I tried this:

```
@property(nonatomic) SKAction* moveNodeRight;
```

But that did not work either.

Comment: Remove the "[" before SKAction *moveNodeRight, and you don't need the property statement. You can delete that.